# Why is docker compose failing with " ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11.6-alpine3.18 "?

Tags: docker, django, docker-compose

I'm new to docker, trying to build a website by following a online course but i was struck with this error in the beginning itself

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13
LABEL maintainer="rohitgajula"

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    rm -rf /tmp && \
    adduser \
        --disabled-password \
        --no-create-home \
        django-user

ENV PATH="/py/bin:$PATH"

USER django-user
```

Error is

```
[+] Building 1.3s (4/4) FINISHED                                                                                  docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 191B                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 492B                                                                                              0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.9-alpine3.13                                                    1.3s
 => [auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                     0.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.9-alpine3.13:
------
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13
   2 |     LABEL maintainer="rohitgajula"
```

I couldn't find solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your Docker daemon is running. You can check the status of the Docker daemon using the following command:

```
sudo systemctl status docker
```

If it's not running, you can start it using:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

If the issue exists, try "sudo" maybe your user is not root user or does not have permission to run the command.

p.s: comment the command you are using to run the docker.